# What is the word (adjective) for the state of getting stuffed but for water?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm **stuffed** - get enough food

I'm **fed up** with it - get enough something (annoyed)

I'm **drunk** - get enough buzz (alcohol)

I'm **tipsy** - slightly drunk

I'm **lushed** - get enough buzz (alcohol)

**Question:**

> In what way can I describe the state of getting enough water (pop, juice, coffee...) with one word *like (stuffed, drunk..)*

Comment: There probably isn't a good single word for this.  If you try to force it you'll end up with something less natural sounding (like in Cantalouping's answer), so it's probably better not to ask for a single word.

Comment: I've never actually *heard* anyone use the word **lushed**.  It is coming back into vogue?

Comment: Agreed with @Tᴚoɯɐuo - *a lush*, yes, but "lushed" as a verb?  I've never heard it.

Comment: Funny enough, I don't know a good adjective for it in *any* language I know...

Comment: In the context of being offered food *or* drink, if you don't feel like you want anything to eat or drink, a perfectly normal way to refuse (in a casual setting) is "No thanks, *I'm good*".  In this context, "I'm good" simply means that you're not hungry or thirsty and that you don't really feel like having any food or drink.

Comment: Did you want a word for *enough*, or for *too much*? Your examples mostly sound like *too much* (**stuffed**, in particular, usually means you've eaten too much, whereas **full** means you've eaten enough), but the text of your question asks for *getting enough water*.

Comment: This would also be a good question for english.stackexchange. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could say, "I've drunk too much water and now I'm feeling **bloated**."

Comment: Or even "filled".

Answer (score 11):

We use the word waterlogged at work. I know this just might be our own way of expressing one's feeling about having drank too much water, but everyone understands what we mean.

> I have drank so much water, I feel waterlogged.

Merrian-Webster Dictionary

> - So filled or soaked with water as to be heavy or hard to manage
> - Saturated with water

Answer (score 2):

I believe **overhydrated** is the word you're looking for.

> I'm overhydrated.

This would mean you've had too much water. You would just use **hydrated** to say you've had enough water.

With regards to the other words, *get enough* is not the correct term. Words like *stuffed*, *fed up*, *drunk*, *lush* all relate to having too much. These are all terms you use when you've had too much to drink or eat, or annoyed to a point of significance.

Comment: This isn't really a word you would use in casual conversation.  In fact, I don't think I've ever heard "overhydrated" used in the context of a human being.  In the context of sports or fitness practice you might hear "well hydrated" when talking about an athlete getting enough fluids to stay at top performance, however.

Comment: I agree and I would defer to Tᴚoɯɐuo's answer *bloated* as being the best choice for most contexts. However, with regards to meeting the specs without any qualifiers or context, this is as close to technically correct as I could manage.

Comment: Overhydrated sounds like water intoxication to me, so that's another reason not to use this lightly

Answer (score 2):

Probably not what you are looking for but the medical term for this in the extreme (dangerous) case is [hyponatraemia](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hyponatraemia) or "water drunk".

Answer (score 1):

My first choice of a word to describe this state would be '**quenched**'

Comment: Here's a very old-fashioned term for complete satisfaction: **slaked**.